# Linking ChChart control to Spreadsheet control data

Tags: excel, vba, charts, controls, spreadsheet

I want to be able to embed a chart control in a VBA form, allowing the user to click on parts of the control, which will populate a hidden spreadsheet with data with the X & Y values clicked.

I got as far as adding the "Microsoft Office Chat 11.0" and "Microsoft Office Spreadsheet 11.0" controls using the Additional Controls mechanism and placing one of each on the form. However, for the life of me I can't seem to bind the chart to the data contained in the spreadsheet. One option I considered was

```
Dim SpdShtCtr As Spreadsheet
Dim ChartControl As ChChart

Dim XValues() As Variant, YValues() As Variant
XValues = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(SpdShtCtrl.Range("XValues"))
YValues = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(SpdShtCtrl.Range("YValues"))

Dim c
Set c = ChartControl.Constants

With ChartControl
    .Clear
    .Charts.Add
    With .Charts(0).SeriesCollection.Add
        .Caption = "Data"
        .SetData c.vbDimCategories, c.chDataLiteral, XValues
        .SetData c.vbDimValues, c.chDataLiteral, YValues
    End With
End With
```

The problem with this is that it is not dynamic - if the data in the spreadsheet changes, the chart will not automatically update. Also, this does not work. I get the error "Object does not support this property or method" on `.SetData ...`

The other option was something like this

```
Dim SpdShtCtr As Spreadsheet
Dim ChartControl As ChChart

Dim XValues As Range, YValues As Range
Set XValues = SpdShtCtrl.Range("XValues")
Set YValues = SpdShtCtrl.Range("YValues")

Dim c
Set c = ChartControl.Constants

With ChartControl
    .DataSource = SpdShtCtrl
    .Clear
    .Charts.Add
    With .Charts(0).SeriesCollection.Add
        .Caption = "Data"
        .SetData c.vbDimCategories, c.chWORKSHEETRANGECONSTANT, XValues
        .SetData c.vbDimValues, c.chWORKSHEETRANGECONSTANT, YValues
    End With
End With
```

But I don't know if this is the correct way to bind these controls together, and even if it is, what the constant definitions should be, in place of `WORKSHEETRANGECONSTANT`, to define linking to a worksheet range.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added a ChartSpace (=ChartSpace1) and a Spreadsheet (=Spreadsheet1) to a Userform and did it like this:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim chc As ChChart

    With Spreadsheet1
        For i = 1 To 3 ' just filling sample Data to Spreadsheet
            .Cells(i, 1) = i
            .Cells(i, 2) = i + 2
        Next
    End With

    Set chc = ChartSpace1.Charts.Add
    chc.Type = chChartTypeScatterSmoothLineMarkers
    ChartSpace1.DataSource = Spreadsheet1 ' linking the Spreadsheet and the Chart

    chc.SeriesCollection.Add
    With chc.SeriesCollection(0)
        .SetData chDimSeriesNames, 0
        .SetData chDimCategories, 0
        .SetData chDimXValues, 0, "A1:A3" ' setting the x coordinate range
        .SetData chDimYValues, 0, "B1:B3" ' setting the y coordinate range
    End With
    chc.HasLegend = True
End Sub
```

Works for me, but i don't know if this does everything you need.

Comment: Thanks @MiVoth, that is a good go. Unfortunately the first `.SetData` call fails for me with "Run-time error '5': Invalid procedure call or argument". Here is my code: http://pastebin.com/YaebnCha. How is what I coded different? Are we both using version 11.0 of the controls?

Comment: Cancel that, I had some superfluous code that threw a spanner in the works. This sample does the job http://pastebin.com/HNGUwkba Good job @MiVoth